# Need to get name data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, getjson

I need to get the name from JSON file what is wrong wit this code?
i would like to get the name value from each of the results and add them to the body.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script>
                    $.ajax({ 
                   type: "GET",
                   dataType: "json",
                   url: "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise.json?category=8&language=2",
                   success: function(data){
                       $.each(data,function(index,object){
                           $("body").append("<div>"+object.name +"</div><br/>")
                       })
                   }
                });
                </script>

            </head>

            <body>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: What does the `data` argument in your success callback look like if you log it?

Comment: it shows the data from the json file

Comment: @Axwell Post an example of the JSON. You're probably misreading the structure.

Comment: @Barmar how would i read the structure for this JSON file

Comment: Open the URL in your browser. Use jsonlint.com to format it nicely if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem is that you are using the wrong object to iterate.

if you run this snippet you can see the returned object on the console.

```js
$.ajax({ 
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise.json?category=8&language=2",
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data)
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as you can see, you need to iterate over `data.results`, so this code should work:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise.json?category=8&language=2",
   success: function(data){
       if(data.results){
           $.each(data.results,function(index,object){
               $("body").append("<div>"+object.name +"</div><br/>")
           })
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: Need `data.results` in the argument to `$.each`.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` argument supplied to the success callback comes in as an Object with a results property that is an Array of Objects.

Rather than passing in the whole `data` object to $.each you should just give it the results array like so:

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data.results, function(index, object){
        $("body").append("<div>"+object.name +"</div><br/>")
    })
}
```

Comment: This is the same as Toug's answer.

Comment: Should I remove it @Barmar? I'm unsure of the protocol. I made this before the other answer was edited

Comment: I usually delete my own answer if it's essentially the same as someone else's, unless I've added something extra in the explanation. But I'm also not looking for reputation bumps, I've got plenty to spare. :)